# Show that $24\leq P(\alpha)\leq 63$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

> Let $p$ be the polynomial defined by :

$$P(x)=2x^{3}+x^2-22x+24$$
>
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-2\leq \alpha \leq 0$ show that 
$$24\leq P(\alpha)\leq 63$$

My thoughts:

note that $P(\alpha)=(2\alpha-3)(\alpha-2)(\alpha+4)$ then

- $ -7 \leq (2\alpha-3)\leq -3 $
- $ -4\leq (\alpha-2)\leq -2 $
- $ 2 \leq (\alpha+4)\leq 4 $
- Am i on the right way  ?

beware : the problem the level of that exercise does'nt allow the notion of dérivability

Answer (score 0):

By extreme value theorem, the curve attains its maxima and minima in this compact set (i.e. closed and bounded set)

It achieves the extrema either at the boundary or stationary point. We already know the boundaries, so just find the stationary points.

Taking the first derivative we get

$ f'(x) = 6x^2 + 2x - 22 $
The roots are 1.7554270991117993 and -2.0887604324451328, so they are not in the range of interest.

So are we need to check is the boundaries.

$ P(0) = 24 $

$ P(-2) = 56 $

So the function actually is within the range of $ 24 \le P(\alpha) \le 56 $, so it is definitely less than 63 as well.

A plot can prove my claim is true:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can write
$$
p(x) = 24 - x \cdot q(x),
$$
where
\begin{gather*}
q(x) = 22 - x - 2x^2 \\
= 22\tfrac{1}{8} - 2\left(x + \tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2.
\end{gather*}
Given that $-2 \leqslant x \leqslant 0$, we have
$$
\lvert x + \tfrac{1}{4} \rvert < 2,
$$
therefore $q(x) > 22\tfrac{1}{8} - 8 > 0$, therefore $-xq(x) \geqslant 0$, therefore $p(x) \geqslant 24$.

Now consider separately the two possible cases (a) $-\tfrac{3}{2} \leqslant x \leqslant 0$, (b) $-2 \leqslant x \leqslant -\tfrac{3}{2}$.

In case (a), because always $q(x) \leqslant 22\tfrac{1}{8} < 24$, we have $-xq(x) < 36$, therefore $p(x) <60$.

In case (b), we have $\lvert x + \tfrac{1}{4} \rvert \geqslant \tfrac{5}{4}$, therefore
\begin{gather*}
q(x) \leqslant 22\tfrac{1}{8} - 2 \cdot \left( \tfrac{25}{16} \right)
= 22\tfrac{1}{8} - 3\tfrac{1}{8} = 19 \\
\text{(or, more neatly, 
$q(x) \leqslant 22\tfrac{1}{8} - 2\left(1 + \tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2 =
q(1) = 19$),}
\end{gather*}
therefore $-xq(x) \leqslant 38$, therefore $p(x) \leqslant 62$.

Therefore, for all $x$ such that $-2 \leqslant x \leqslant 0$, we have $24 \leqslant p(x) \leqslant 62$.